# mySql SELECT GROUP_CONCAT query not return all data in longtext cell

Tags: mysql, group-concat, longtext

I have a cell that contains a very long string.
If I use this query:

```
SELECT dettPDE FROM bollaOutDett WHERE idDoc>0 GROUP BY idDoc;
```

I have no problem, but in some cases I need to use this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(dettPDE='',NULL, dettPDE) SEPARATOR '|') AS dettPDESch 
FROM bollaOutDett 
WHERE idDoc>0 
GROUP BY idDoc;
```

and in this case dettPDESch not return correctly.

Here the test code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bollaOutDett;
CREATE TABLE bollaOutDett (idDoc int, dettPDE longtext);
INSERT INTO bollaOutDett (idDoc, dettPDE)
VALUES 
    (1, '[{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"3","codProdotto":"2SA1264N","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H1","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H2","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H3","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H4","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"3","codProdotto":"2SA1264N","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"J1","artLot":"0","lotto":""}]'),
    (2, ''),
    (3, '[{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"3","codProdotto":"2SA1264N","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H1","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H2","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H3","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"H4","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"3","codProdotto":"2SA1264N","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"J1","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"J2","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"J3","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"J4","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"3","codProdotto":"2SA1264N","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"K1","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"K2","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"K3","artLot":"0","lotto":""},{"tab":"PArticoli","id":"879","codProdotto":"2SA1267","qta":"1","artSer":"1","seriale":"K4","artLot":"0","lotto":""}]'),
    (4, '');


SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(dettPDE='',NULL, dettPDE) SEPARATOR '|') AS dettPDESch 
FROM bollaOutDett 
WHERE idDoc>0 
GROUP BY idDoc;

SELECT dettPDE
FROM bollaOutDett 
WHERE idDoc>0 
GROUP BY idDoc
```

Any suggestion?

Original link to code: [here](https://rextester.com/WNMYX44274)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a limit for group_concat  length

> Default Value 1024

you can  change this limit  using a proper set

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

The max limit for

> The maximum value for group_concat_max_len for 64-bit is
>   18446744073709551615
>
> The maximum value for group_concat_max_len for 32-bit is 4294967295

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Comment: Thanks... is there a method to set it only once or I have to set in each query that I make ?

Comment: the group_concat_max_len  should be a param in sql.in  [mysqld] section so you could assign the value you need  in sql.ini  in this way at startup of your db the new value is used